# Install git from source

Tags: make, git, source

I am attempting to install git from source to use last version of git.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

```
$ tar -zxf git-2.0.1.tar.gz
$ cd git-2.0.1
$ make prefix=/usr/local all
$ sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

-

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.1
```

What did I do wrong?

Kubuntu 14.04, amd64.

Comment: What should I input?

Comment: Maybe no, depends upon what you want to do. What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: Why not install it by apt-get ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the old version:

```
sudo apt-get purge git
```

Add the new Version to the $PATH:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin/git:$PATH
cd
source .bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

While installing from source has its moments, you can use the [Git PPA](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: Before you begin, you need to install the software that git depends on. This is all available in the default repositories, so we can update our local package index and then install the packages: sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext unzip

Comment: @HanyAlsamman I suppose this comment was meant to be on the question?

Comment: yeah , sorry but im on mobile i posted it here by wrong

Comment: Is there a place to download git compiled binaries and just extract them? I need a compiled version of GIT on a folder (Not system wide) for single application. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: @Royi doesn't look like it. git-scm.com doesn't list any binary downloads for Linux that I can find. Practically every distro packages git, so I don't think the git people think there's a need to publish Linux binaries.

Comment: @muru, I really wish I a statically linked binaries of GIT were to be found.

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be that the system installs `git` into a location that has higher priority than where you're placing your `git` binary.  You could test for this by examining your `$PATH`:

```
echo $PATH
```

You could adjust your `$PATH` variable so that `/usr/local/bin` has higher priority by running something like this, or adding this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

---

However, you should take a few things into consideration.  If you're installing this at a system level, then you should remove the `apt`-controlled package using `apt-get remove git`.  If you chose to do this, you should make sure that your `git` install is solid and has no issues.  Other things on your system rely on `git`.

If you chose to do this, you should omit `--prefix` flags from all compilation instructions, and instead run `./configure`, and allow that to determine your prefix.  This means that different systems will know how to best install binaries, and you allow the system to come up with the details.

Alternatively, you can install a binary for *your user only*, which is probably best practice, and a good idea until you become more familiar with compilation, binaries and packages.  In this case, you would want to set a `--prefix` of something like `--prefix=/home/username/.local/` or `--prefix=/home/username/` which will place the binary in the `bin/` directory under your prefix.  Then, you just ensure that that is part of your `$PATH` by adding this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/home/username/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Remember that anytime you edit your `.bashrc` or other `source`'d files, you need to re-`source` `.bashrc` or restart your terminal:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```